# WF behavior by windows.open

Tags: c#

I understand this is a very broad problem, but I am not able t figure out how to approach this issue. I have researched internet but no significant suggestions.

We have two servers one is running IIS7 and the older one that is running IIS6. The same website is deployed to both of them. When we hit the website the expected behavior is to have the login page open in a full screen separate window as per the following code:

```
window.open("Login.aspx?from=default", "login", "scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=yes,height=" + xheight + ",width=" + xwidth)
```

The website behaves differently on the IIS6 server as the login page opens in the same window and not separately. Can't seem to understand why. Any pointers on how to approach this or any explanations will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not clear on how this has anything to do with Windows Workflow Foundation. As an aside, my first thought is "standardize your IIS deployments."

Comment: Where are you getting the values for `xheight` and `xwidth`? Further, what page is executing this JavaScript?

Comment: default.aspx is the page, does xheight and xwidth has anything to do with it? Those values are just constants. We need both the deployments.